# Parsing data to create a json data object with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, google-bigquery

Here is my data from google bigquery to parse:

```
{
    u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse',
    u'rows': [
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'995'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1600'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'942'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1607'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'937'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1599'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'894'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1598'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'848'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1592'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'841'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1590'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'786'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1603'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'779'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1609'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'762'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1597'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'753'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1594'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'740'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1596'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'738'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1612'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'718'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1590'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'717'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1610'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'715'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1602'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'680'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1606'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'674'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1603'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'639'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1603'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'637'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1603'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'634'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1590'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'633'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1599'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'616'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1596'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'614'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1596'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'612'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1595'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'607'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1603'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'579'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1593'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'570'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1600'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'541'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1599'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'525'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1608'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'520'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1599'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'518'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1602'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'486'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1595'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'470'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1593'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'433'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1609'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'429'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1607'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'421'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1611'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'399'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1592'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'363'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'0'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'353'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1594'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'287'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1609'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'106'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'0'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            u'f': [
                {
                    u'v': u'the'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'57'
                },
                {
                    u'v': u'1609'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    u'jobReference': {
        u'projectId': u'670640819051',
        u'jobId': u'job_5bf745fcee8b470e997d8ea90f380e68'
    },
    u'jobComplete': True,
    u'totalRows': u'42',
    u'schema': {
        u'fields': [
            {
                u'type': u'STRING',
                u'name': u'word',
                u'mode': u'NULLABLE'
            },
            {
                u'type': u'INTEGER',
                u'name': u'word_count',
                u'mode': u'NULLABLE'
            },
            {
                u'type': u'INTEGER',
                u'name': u'corpus_date',
                u'mode': u'NULLABLE'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Being a Python newbee, I really have no idea about how to go about parsing this data to create a json object like below:

```
[
     {'count': 200, 'year': 2008},
     {'count': 240, 'year': 2010},
     {'count': 290, 'year': 2009}
]
```

Can any one give me any hint about how to get started?

**Example**

```
[{u'v': u'the'}, {u'v': u'995'}, {u'v': u'1600'}]
```

In this for the word `'the'`, `count` is 995 and `year` is 1600. And so it follows.

Comment: hi, Where does "year" and "count" comes from?

Comment: In your example, how are you distinguishing that `{u'v': u'995'}` represents `count` and `{u'v': u'1600'}` represents `year`?

Comment: Probably by the index in the sequence.

Comment: @BrendanWood the first one is the count and the second one is the year.Dat how it has to be

Comment: yeah. You will have to use the index number 1 to get the count and the index number 2 to get the year.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If 'Z' is your big dictionary, on 'response' you will get the structure you need.

```
import json

response = []
for row in z['rows']:
    for key, dict_list in row.iteritems():
        count = dict_list[1]
        year = dict_list[2]
        response.append({'count': count['v'], 'year' : year['v']})

 print json.dumps(response)
```

On response you will get the following:

```
[{'count': u'995', 'year': u'1600'},
 {'count': u'942', 'year': u'1607'},
 {'count': u'937', 'year': u'1599'},
 {'count': u'894', 'year': u'1598'},
 {'count': u'848', 'year': u'1592'},
 {'count': u'841', 'year': u'1590'},
 {'count': u'786', 'year': u'1603'},
 {'count': u'779', 'year': u'1609'},
 {'count': u'762', 'year': u'1597'},
 {'count': u'753', 'year': u'1594'},
 {'count': u'740', 'year': u'1596'},
 {'count': u'738', 'year': u'1612'},
 {'count': u'718', 'year': u'1590'},
 {'count': u'717', 'year': u'1610'},
 {'count': u'715', 'year': u'1602'},
 {'count': u'680', 'year': u'1606'},
 {'count': u'674', 'year': u'1603'},
 {'count': u'639', 'year': u'1603'},
 {'count': u'637', 'year': u'1603'},
 {'count': u'634', 'year': u'1590'},
 {'count': u'633', 'year': u'1599'},
 {'count': u'616', 'year': u'1596'},
 {'count': u'614', 'year': u'1596'},
 {'count': u'612', 'year': u'1595'},
 {'count': u'607', 'year': u'1603'},
 {'count': u'579', 'year': u'1593'},
 {'count': u'570', 'year': u'1600'},
 {'count': u'541', 'year': u'1599'},
 {'count': u'525', 'year': u'1608'},
 {'count': u'520', 'year': u'1599'},
 {'count': u'518', 'year': u'1602'},
 {'count': u'486', 'year': u'1595'},
 {'count': u'470', 'year': u'1593'},
 {'count': u'433', 'year': u'1609'},
 {'count': u'429', 'year': u'1607'},
 {'count': u'421', 'year': u'1611'},
 {'count': u'399', 'year': u'1592'},
 {'count': u'363', 'year': u'0'},
 {'count': u'353', 'year': u'1594'},
 {'count': u'287', 'year': u'1609'},
 {'count': u'106', 'year': u'0'},
 {'count': u'57', 'year': u'1609'}]
```

I believe its what you need. 
Than only use [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and do a `json.dumps` to the response and that's it.

Comment: There is a typo respone = [] should be response = []

Answer (score 6):

You can easily convert python objects into JSON objects and viceversa using the module json.
Foundamentally there are only 2 classes: **JSONEncoder** and **JSONDecoder**: the first turns python collections into JSON strings, the second a JSON string into a Python object.

Examples:

```
from json import JSONEncoder

jsonString = JSONEncoder().encode({
  "count": 222, 
  "year": 2012
})
```

the code above will generate a JSON string from a Python dictionary

```
from json import JSONDecoder

pyDictionary = JSONDecoder().decode('{"count": 222, "year": 2012}')
```

the code above will generate a python dictionary from a JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Version `0.28.0` and later of the [`google-cloud-bigquery` library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) use a `Row` class to parse rows from a table or query.

For example to print out the results from a query with a schema

```
[
   {
        u'type': u'STRING',
        u'name': u'word',
        u'mode': u'NULLABLE'
    },
    {
        u'type': u'INTEGER',
        u'name': u'word_count',
        u'mode': u'NULLABLE'
    },
    {
        u'type': u'INTEGER',
        u'name': u'corpus_date',
        u'mode': u'NULLABLE'
    },
]
```

as in your example, one could do

```
query = client.query('...')
rows = query.result()
for row in rows:
    # Access by column index.
    print('word: {}'.format(row[0]))
    # Access by column name.
    # The library parses the result into an integer object,
    # based on the schema.
    print('word_count: {}'.format(row['word_count']))
    # Access by column name, like an attribute.
    print('corpus_date: {}'.format(row.corpus_date))
```

In version `0.29.0` (not yet released as of 2017-12-04), there will be methods for `keys()`, `values()`, `items()`, and `get()`, just like a built-in dictionary object. (Added in [PR #4393](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/4393)) So, to convert rows to a JSON-like dictionary in `0.29.0`:

```
query = client.query('...')
rows = query.result()
for row in rows:
    row_json = dict(row.items())
```